# Python regex replace backslash or frontslash

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to replace backslashes or front slashes in a string with double backslashes. I've tried a couple of things but it doesn't seem to work.¨

My work so far:

```
string = 'C:\Users\Victor\Dropbox\Private\files\test.txt'

f = re.sub(r'[\\\/]', '\\\\', string)
```

This prints the string:

```
'C:\Users\Victor\Dropbox\Privateiles   est.txt'
```

But what i really want is a string that looks like this:

```
'C:\\Users\\Victor\\Dropbox\\Private\\files\\test.txt'
```

So that when i print the string it will look like the original

```
'C:\Users\Victor\Dropbox\Private\files\test.txt'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just convert that string to a raw string:

```
>>> string = r'C:\Users\Victor\Dropbox\Private\files\test.txt'
>>> string
'C:\\Users\\Victor\\Dropbox\\Private\\files\\test.txt'
>>> print string
C:\Users\Victor\Dropbox\Private\files\test.txt
```

Comment: What about strings as variables?

string = raw_input('test: ')

How do i make it interpret the string as a raw string?

Comment: I don't know if the edit was supposed to answer my question, but it did not. I still can't interpret user input as a raw string

Comment: +1 for raw string. :) @VictorVH if the answer is correct please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are really getting at is path manipulation, I'd just use the `os` module.

```
>>> s = r'C:\Users\Victor\Dropbox\Private\files\test.txt'
>>> import os
>>> os.path.normcase(s)
'C:\\Users\\Victor\\Dropbox\\Private\\files\\test.txt'
```

[`os.path.normcase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normcase)

> Normalize the case of a pathname. On `Unix` and `Mac OS X`, this returns the path unchanged; on case-insensitive filesystems, it converts the path to lowercase. **On Windows, it also converts forward slashes to backward slashes**. Raise a `TypeError` if the type of path is not `str` or `bytes`.

Comment: This makes sure to treat the string as a path or?

Comment: Please read the description I just added for `normcase`, it is safe to use as a path after using that function. Note that it is still a `string` literal as far as python is concerned

Comment: I just tried this. It returns an invalid string: 
c:\users\victor\dropbox\private ilewatcher\main.py

Comment: Hmm that is strange, I copy-pasted that right out of my IDLE terminal. What IDE are you using, and on what OS?

Comment: +1 for using `os`. Also, you may be interested in raw strings which don't interpret the backslash as an escape character. `r"C:\Users\Victor\Dropbox\Private\files\test.txt"`.

Comment: Yes i've saw it work with raw strings. How do you make a variable into a raw string?

Comment: Thanks @user3689902 I have edited my answer to include this. @VictorVH type `r` before your string.

Comment: I know, but how to i do that with variables?

string = raw_input('test: ')

How do i make it interpret the string as a raw string?