# Python 2.7 Filepath Regex match Too many )'s

Tags: .net, regex, windows, python-2.7, filepath

I am trying to match a specific word in between backslashes in the windows file path of a file.
The value to match is "Psb+" for this case

X:\Guli\Proc(Loops)\Read\Psb+\İngil\Fate\5.0X[Lxss.] [Psb+] Instructions.txt

Due to software limitations I cannot use import os but I can use Pythonnet.

My regex is like this

```
pFilePath = "X:\Guli\Proc\(Loops)\Read\Psb+\İngil\Fate\5.0X\[Lxss.] [Psb+] Instructions.txt"
searchtext = "Psb+"    
pm = re.search(r'(?i)(?<="\\")' + searchtext + r'(?="\\")', pFilePath)
```

It runs OK in the Visual Studio Core but when I try it on my environment, I get this error:

```
parsing ............. - Too many )'s.
```

I am stuck with this. Is there a more clever way of doing this?

Comment: You have to escape the backslashes in `pFilePath`.

Comment: Is there any way to automatically convert the pFilePath instead of manually escaping every illegal character?
I cannot import os.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24769242/372239 https://stackoverflow.com/q/54713670/372239

Comment: pFilePath.replace(r"\" , r"\\")
this gives error and doesn't work
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of things,

I got around the issue by implementing Directory.GetDirectories Method using IronPython.

```
import clr
from System.IO import Path, File, Directory
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=netcore-3.1

Then I found a way to import os by using symbolic links.